# Executing multiple create table statements in a single SqlCeCommand

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

I'm trying to run a SQL statement against a SQL Server CE database that will create a couple of tables in a database.

My SQL statement is really simple...

```
CREATE TABLE APPOINTMENTS 
(
     [SUBJECT] NVARCHAR(50) NULL, 
     START NVARCHAR(21) NULL, 
     ENDDATE NVARCHAR(21) NULL, 
     NOTES NVARCHAR(250) NULL
);

CREATE TABLE AppointmentsRemove
(
     [SUBJECT] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);
```

Then I'm running it using the following code....

NOTE: I'm having to create the `.sdf` database file as well as run the script against it:

```
using (SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(connectionString))
{
    SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand();

    SqlCeEngine en = new SqlCeEngine(connectionString);
    en.CreateDatabase();

    cmd.Connection = conn;
    conn.Open();

    //Create the initial tables..
    cmd.CommandText =
        @"CREATE TABLE APPOINTMENTS ([SUBJECT] NVARCHAR(50) NULL, START NVARCHAR(21) NULL, ENDDATE NVARCHAR(21) NULL, NOTES NVARCHAR(250) NULL); 
            CREATE table AppointmentsRemove([SUBJECT]  nvarchar(50) not null);";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

I keep getting the following error though...

> There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 2,Token line offset = 29,Token in error = CREATE ]

I've done some experimenting and it works if I run each of the create table statements on there own, but as soon as they are put together I get the above error.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to execute them at the same time?

Comment: I've got a text file with all the statements in there, which I read in so if someone needs to make an edit they can just change the text file, I removed the call to function that retrieves this so it would be a bit clearer on here.

Comment: I haven't tried.. but Just guessing put `GO;` between two statements

Comment: that gives me a different error... There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 136,Token in error = GO ]

Comment: Maybe it's just not possible what I'm attempting

Comment: You're using `SqlCeCommand` so im assuming your using SQL Server Compact. This supports a single command at a time.

Comment: Apart from anything, its a terrible idea to allow users to modify the SQL executed by your program.

Comment: yeah it is SQL server compact. I wasn't aware that it only did a single command.

Comment: Users cannot edit this file only a dev. I know this is a bad idea, but unfortunately it is all I've got to work with

Comment: @Martin Well your going to have to write a parser to extract single queries out of the text file. I suggest defining a separator string between queries, such as //NEW//. Something which will never appear in your actual SQL queries.

Comment: Each SQL statement is on a new line so I'm just using a streamreader and  reading each line in one at a time.